# fetch column2 value corresponding to column1 maximum,minimum?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to fetch column2 values for max(column1). help me. I got to find the date corresponding to the max(price) and min(price) in database.

```
$str="select MAX(psq_price),MIN(psq_price),AVG(psq_price) from crawl_archives where p_id=2570";
```

I found max , min values from this query.. Need to find the date column corresponding to the maximum price ..

Comment: 1. what u tried 2. give your code 3. give more details 4. to get good help.5. u are using php tag ?where is php here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    select date ,  MAX(psq_price),MIN(psq_price)
    from mytable 

    group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
select * 
from <table> t
join (select max(price) as max_price
      from <table>
      group by <col1>
     )a
on a.col1=t.col1
and a.max_price=t.price
```